# How to solve the equation $\sqrt{5}\cos(x/2)+2\sin(x/2) = 1.2$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the equation $\sqrt{5}\cos(x/2)+2\sin(x/2) = 1.2$.

If not because of the half angle, I can convert to $r(\sin x - \alpha)$.  I tried brute force solving it by using half-angle formula, equation gets haywire.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What's wrong with that approach you have? I don't see a need to use the half angle formulas. Just solve like you would normally and then multiply the answer at the end by $2$.

Comment: Couldnt solve it due to Sin x/2 is more than 1

Comment: Why not just solve $\sqrt 5\cos(y)+2\sin(y)=1.2$ and then solve $y=\frac x2$? You may also divide on both sides by $2$ or $\sqrt5$ to simplify the equation

Comment: Then half angle won't solve your problem, because that would mean the equation has no solutions. However, more likely is that you did the simplification wrong, because I did not run into that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

\begin{align}
y&=x/2\\
\sqrt{5}\cos(y)&=1.2-2\sin(y)
\end{align}
Square both sides:
\begin{equation}
5\cos^2(y)=1.44-4.8\sin(y)+4\sin^2(y)
\end{equation}
Add $5\sin^2(y)$:
\begin{equation}
5=1.44-4.8\sin(y)+9\sin^2(y)
\end{equation}
Now you have a quadratic polynomial which you can solve for $\sin(y)$ with the abc-formula. Check which solution fits your initial equation.

Comment: Thanks :). When you said square both sides, i got my lightbulb already.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the equation :

$\sqrt{5}\cos\left(\dfrac x2\right)+2\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac65\;.$

Since $\;\sqrt{\left(\sqrt5\right)^2+2^2}=3\;,\;$ we divide by $3$ both sides of the previous equation, consequently we get :

$\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}3\cos\left(\dfrac x2\right)+\dfrac23\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac25\;.$

By letting $\;\alpha=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt5}3\right)\in\left]0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right[\;,\;$ it follows that

$\sin\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt5}3\;$ and $\;\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt5}3\right)^2}=\dfrac23\;.$

Hence, the equation turns into :

$\sin\alpha\cos\left(\dfrac x2\right)+\cos\alpha\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac25\;\;,$

$\sin\left(\alpha+\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac25\;.$

Therefore ,

$\alpha+\dfrac x2=(-1)^k\arcsin\left(\dfrac25\right)+k\pi\;,\;$ where $\;k\in\Bbb Z\;.$

Consequently, all the solutions of the equation are :

$x=2(-1)^k\arcsin\left(\dfrac25\right)-2\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt5}3\right)+2k\pi\;,\;\;\forall k\in\Bbb Z\,.$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [half-angle tangent substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/half-angle-tangent-substitution/).

Let $t = \tan(\tfrac x4 )$. Then

$$
\begin{cases}
\cos(\tfrac x2) = \frac{1-t^2}{1 + t^2} \\
\sin(\tfrac x2) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}
\end{cases} 
$$

We get

$$
\sqrt5 \cdot \frac{1-t^2}{1 + t^2} + 2 \cdot \frac{2t}{1+t^2} = \frac65
$$

Rearranging shows that it's a quadratic equation, so $t = \frac{10 \pm 3 \sqrt{21}}{6 + 5\sqrt5}$.

Can you finish it off from here?

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know half angle tangent can be used for half angle sin and cos.